Old mini series about the life of a lady during the late 19th century
I watched a old mini series with my parents on VHS in the early 90s (probably made in the 70s or 80s). I asked my parents but they can't remember what it was.
All I can remember about it is that it was about a lady (I think the course of her life as young lady to old woman), her family, etc. (not Woman of Substance series). 
I remember scenes at a train station when she was younger and then again when she was older. I also remember at some point the towards the end of the series there were two men talking about someone who died on the Titanic, this was in a restaurant while having a drink) so I presume the series time period was up until 1912. I can't say for sure but I think it took place in England.

You might want to provide a more descriptive question title.

Was the movie British-made? Did you watch it in England or somewhere else? Were there any recognizable stars in it? You say it made an impression on you, but the only things you told us about were that a woman goes to a train station twice and some men talk about the titanic. What sort of impression did it leave and why?

I have not seen this in a very long time, but could it be the 1968 version of Portrait of a Lady?
